# gradle dependencies .so file

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I use gradle build android project, dependencies .so file.

```
compile 'com.epwk:liblocSDK4d:1.0:armeabi@so'
compile 'com.epwk:libjpush170:1.0:armeabi@so'
compile 'com.epwk:libMtaNativeCrash:1.0:armeabi@so'
compile 'com.epwk.mips:libMtaNativeCrash:1.0:mips@so'
compile 'com.epwk.x86:libMtaNativeCrash:1.0:x86@so'
compile 'com.epwk.armeabiv7a:libjpush170:1.0:v7a@so'
compile 'com.epwk.armeabiv7a:libMtaNativeCrash:1.0:v7a@so'
```

I could see them in the external libraries.

When I run this project it get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jpush170: findLibrary returned null
```

What should I do？

```
Ignoring class path entry C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.epwk\liblocSDK4d\1.0\24c2f73ec32323d8f0eac88b58731ae3336e4c93\liblocSDK4
d-1.0-armeabi.so
Ignoring class path entry C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.epwk\libjpush170\1.0\4e0296ffc64d57753e974110682baedd4a127d17\libjpush17
0-1.0-armeabi.so
Ignoring class path entry C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-
2.1\com.epwk\libMtaNativeCrash\1.0\beefa8d28bf7c2490443d74623c2c9595d329a86\libM
taNativeCrash-1.0-armeabi.so
```

Comment: I' m afarid you cannot import native libs use this way.

Comment: i think you should mannuly put the native lib to your project.